# Difference between console.log and document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, console.log

```
const arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
arr.forEach(function(val){
console.log(val);
})
```

| Output |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

```
const arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
arr.forEach(function(val){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=val;
})
```

| Output |
| --- |
| 5 |

My question is why I am getting different output even after using the same lines of codes.

Comment: Because the loops do completely different things. Why do you think logging to the console is the same as updating some element's HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code below:

```
const arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
arr.forEach(function(val){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml=val;
})
```

for each loop, it say html element with id demo set new innerHtml. So it will get value 1 and then overwrite by 2, 3, 4, 5. Finally, your final inner html would be 5.
To show all arr value, you need to put to separate element look like this code:

```
const arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
arr.forEach(function(val){
document.getElementById("demo" + val).innerHtml=val; 
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was skipping.

Answer (score 0):

Console.log prints your output to console. documet.getElementById() return an element that has the Id attributes with the specified value.
Both are totally different.

Answer (score 0):

The method `console.log` prints the `val` for each of the array values:

```
const arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
arr.forEach(function(val){
    console.log(val);
})
```

However, the document.getElementById().innerHtml will update the `innerHtml` of the element:

```
const arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
arr.forEach(function(val){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml=val;
})
```

In the code above you are **overwriting the current value** of element's `innerHtml`(body).
You need to **concatenate** or **append** the current value of the `innerHtml` with the `val` every time.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += val;
```